# jquery datepicker not working in ftl

Tags: jquery, datepicker, freemarker

I'm trying to use jquery datepicker in a freemarker file. However the calendar fails to load up when i click on the button. The weird thing is on the same page, there's another field that's using datepicker and worked well.

Here's the text input:

```
<input type="text" id="Form_approvedDate" maxlength="10" size="10" title="Format: yyyy-MM-dd" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:none;background-color:transparent" name="approvedDate" class="hasDatepicker">
```

Here's my button:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"></button>
```

and here's the script that i use to assign datepicker:

```
jQuery("#Form_approvedDate").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '',
                buttonText: '',
                buttonImageOnly: false,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
              });
```

It's driving me nuts, anyone has any idea with this?

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include the button in your html file. Datepicker should create the button element on its own. Also, do not include the 'hasDatepicker' class anywhere in your html. That class is added to the element after that element has been processed by datepicker.

Comment: When i removed the button, the calendar icon is not showing up as well, does this means datepicker is not generating the button?

Comment: argh..my fault, got it fixed after removing the 'hasDatepicker' class from my input, Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need to put the above code with $(document).ready block, just to ensure that the javascript is called only after the dom object is created.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#Form_approvedDate").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '',
                buttonText: '',
                buttonImageOnly: false,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
              });
});
```